# Eliminating hidden copies in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I wanted to ask some Fortran gurus about this issues I have with an up to date version of the Cray Compiler. I have several warnings that although they do not affect correctness, they will probably do for performance. The warning is:

> This argument produces a copy in to a temporary variable.

Here is one of the situations where I get this warning. Within the same file (fem.f90) and module:

```
  call fem( array_local( i, : ), pcor, arcol, inder,    & 
                              ^ 
  ftn-1438 crayftn: CAUTION FFEM, File = fem.f90, Line = 676, Column = 31 
  This argument produces a copy in to a temporary variable.
```

The routine FFEM from where `array_local` is called looks like:

```
-------------------------- 
subroutine ffem( alow, pcor, arcol, inder,  iflag ) 

  integer , intent( in ) :: alow(3), pcor(3) 
  real, intent( in ) :: inder,arcol 
  integer, intent( out ) :: iflag 

  integer::  array_local(5,3) 

 ! within in a loop 
  call fem( array_local( i, : ),  pcor, arcol, inder,    & 
   .......... 
--------------------------
```

And here is `fem` subroutine:

```
-------------------------- 
subroutine fem (ac,  pc, rc, id, flag ) 
 integer, intent( in ) :: ac(3) 
       ....... 
--------------------------
```

I cannot find the way to get rid of that **copy in** which will definitely slow down my code. I was wondering, does anyone know why this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: @francescalus I was thinking more in changes to the code. Perhaps this could also be solved with different compilation options, but I am after code changes to understand it.

Comment: A change of the `fem()` subroutine could also help. Is that an option? I don't see a way how to fix this with compiler options. If the (small) array temporary is on the stack, perhaps it slows the code only slightly.

Comment: @VladimirF it is. What sort of change do you have in mind?

Comment: `integer, intent( in ) :: ac(:)` An explicit interface (best using a module) is necessary.

Comment: You get a similar message with `ifort -check arg_temp_created`. As Fortran subroutine expects a contiguous array, even array slicing such as `array_local( i, : )` require a new array to be created I think. The following may help https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524873

Comment: What further uses of `array_local` are there?  It may simply be that using `array_local(3,5)` and passing `array_local(:,i)` suffices.

Comment: For more you can visit OP's cross-post at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/eiVhBf8p_fo

Answer (score 4):

If `array_local` must be defined as it is and you cannot define it as `(5,3)` as brady shows, you can consider an assumed shape dummy argument

```
subroutine fem (ac,  pc, rc, id, flag ) 
 integer, intent( in ) :: ac(:)
```

array passed there can be non-contiguous and still there is no copy, `ac` will be non-contiguous (strided) too.

You need explicit interfaces for that. That is best achieved by placing the subroutines in a module.

Answer (score 2):

The feasibility of this change depends on your use of `array_local` elsewhere, but you could swap the order:

`integer::  array_local(3,5)`

and then call `fem`:

`call fem( array_local( :, i ),  pcor, arcol, inder,    &`

This will allow the compiler to simply send a reference to the appropriate part of the `array_local` array since columns are ordered contiguously in memory.